# Is it possible to mark a property as dirty in Grails domain?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

We have embedded domain in Grails 2.5.1. When any value inside this embedded domain is changed the owner domain mark property representing embedded domain as dirty. But there is no information which property inside of embedded domain is dirty.

So I would like to somehow mark such property manually - by implementing our own mechanism for marking and detecting such properties and I thought that I could use e.g. markDirty() method of owner domain for it. But this method does not work when it is called from outside.

Is it possible to somehow influence dirtyPropertyNames and in additional any other related properties and method so it will contain embedded domain values?

Than we could use dirtyPropertyNames as usual and it could return something like:
`['embededDomainProperty.changedPropertyName']`